# Date Error in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, date

This one has both me and my boss tearing our hair out in frustration:

I'm running a stored procedure to get some information out of my database. One of the values it returns is a date field. When I manually exec the stored procedure in SQL, I get a value and yet when I write the data out onto the page, I get a value + 1.

So, for example, if SQL says the date should be 12/11/2011, my page is displaying it as 13/11/2011.

It doesn't appear to be a date format issue - my date's coming out of SQL in UK/Europe format and the .NET page is displaying it in UK/Europe format - and as far as I'm aware, I'm not actually adding 1 on when I display the date.

Does anyone have any suggestions for what stupid mistake (and at this point, we're both pretty sure it IS something silly since all my googling hasn't turned up anyone else with this problem) we've made?

The select query is as follows:

```
Select @TotalPrice as Price, Convert(varchar(10),@Departure, 103) as Departure, 
@PImage1 as PImage1, @PImage2 as PImage2, @PImage3 as PImage3, PName, PBath, 
PBed, PMaxSleep, PSwim, PLong, PLat, RIName, CIName, RName, CName, PTShortDesc, 
PTLongDesc 
from Property P, 
     PropertyText PT, 
     Region R, 
     RegionID RI, 
     Country C, 
     CountryID CI 
where P.PID=@PID and P.RIID=RI.RIID and P.CIID=CI.CIID and 
      P.PID=PT.PID and PT.CID=PT.CID and C.CID=R.CID and LCode='EN' and 
      R.RIID=RI.RIID and C.CIID=CI.CIID
```

I'm then writing Departure to a label:

```
DepartureLabel.text = myReader1("Departure")
```

At no stage do I have any DateAdd statements in my page.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check daylight savings time and regional settings. Both on the client and on the server.

Also check the actual value in the table in the SQL server (not by using the client) to find out whether it is the server or the client.

Comment: Server and client are in the same time zone and running on the same settings (plus or minus 20 minutes), and I already have checked the value in SQL. Exec'ing the stored procedure gives me 12/11/2011; running the page gives me 13/11/2011.

Comment: @FrustratedWDotNet: And when you query the database using a query tool?

Comment: Departure is a derived value - it's not actually in a database table so I can't just open a table up and see it. When I run the stored procedure as a whole, it gives me the right value.

Comment: Then it must be the client that mangles it. Without the client code I can't really help you out. Did you debug the code, did you profile the connection to see the results passing from SQL server to the client?

Comment: The entire page code is several thousand lines long (which is why it isn't included), and apart from writing the date value out to a label (code snippet included), I'm not actually doing anything with the date other than displaying it. Debug produces no errors and the warnings relate to visual studio not finding the CSS file. How would I profile the connection?

Comment: Did you try sending it to another label? page? debug it at runtime??? see the value at run time??

Comment: another page yes: same issue; another label - I hadn't tried it, but I just have and, yep, same issue, although that did lead me to an inconsistency - there's a default date that the SP spits out in cases when no date's been selected. THAT, frustratingly, comes out just fine...

Comment: use the Sql Profiler to trace the connection. Debugging the page, breakpoint, could help too

Comment: @FrustratedWDotNet debuging at run time gives you the incorrect value on the reader??? maybe you doing something else on the reader.. what if you create this on a totally different project.. does it work like it should???